# WinForms prints to default printer even if it's not available/connected

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, printing

How can I determine if printer is connected?

Typically this application prints to the default printer but in some cases that printer may not be available.  If so I don't want the job sent to it's queue but rather printed to another available printer.

I understand the PrinterSettings.InstalledPrinters property. Does PrintDocument.PrinterSettings.IsValid return false if a printer is not available?

Does WPF provide this kind of functionality?

My problem is different than [Printing problem in C# windows app - Always prints to default printer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2321412/printing-problem-in-c-windows-app-always-prints-to-default-printer)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First, IsValid checks the value of the PrinterName property to see if it is a valid value, not if the printer is connected.

Second, in WPF it is very easy to do this;

```
 var defaultPrintQueue = LocalPrintServer.GetDefaultPrintQueue();
 if (!defaultPrintQueue.IsNotAvailable)
 {
   //print stuff
 }
```

Check the [docs](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.printing.printqueue.isnotavailable%28VS.100%29.aspx) for more detail: 
In winforms, its a little harder but you can use [WMI](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa394582%28VS.85%29.aspx). Reference System.Management.dll and add the following using statements:

```
using System;
using System.Drawing.Printing;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.Management;
```

To get all default printers:

**NOTE** The following code is likely to be OS dependant to some extent. Check the MSDN docs..

```
 var printerSearcher =
     new ManagementObjectSearcher(
       "SELECT * FROM Win32_Printer where Default = true"
     );
   return printerSearcher.Get();
```

The [WMI documentation for the printer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa394363%28VS.85%29.aspx) object describes some useful structures we can look at; PrinterStatus and WorkOffline. We can use these to write an utility class to check the availability of the printer, also check its WorkOffline state...

```
 public static class PrinterUtility
 {
    public static bool IsOnline(this ManagementBaseObject printer)
    {
        var status = printer["PrinterStatus"];
        var workOffline = (bool)printer["WorkOffline"];
        if (workOffline) return false;

        int statusAsInteger = Int32.Parse(status.ToString());
        switch (statusAsInteger)
        {
            case 3: //Idle
            case 4: //Printing
            case 5: //Warming up
            case 6: //Stopped printing
                return true;
            default:
                return false;
        }
    }

    public static ManagementObjectCollection GetDefaultPrinters()
    {
        var printerSearcher =
          new ManagementObjectSearcher(
            "SELECT * FROM Win32_Printer where Default = true"
          );
        return printerSearcher.Get();
    }
}
```

Now you can combine this with standard WinForms System.Drawing.Printing code:

```
//in a function, far far away from any button click handler :P
foreach(var printer in PrinterUtility.GetDefaultPrinters())
{
  if (printer.IsOnline())
  {
    var pDoc = new PrintDocument(); //or get from PrintDialog
    pDoc.PrinterSettings.PrinterName = printer["Name"].ToString();
    if (pDoc.PrinterSettings.IsValid) //just check WMI didn't tell fibs about the name
    {
      //do printy things       
    }
  }
}
```

Hope this helps

Comment: I'll be trying this as soon as I have time.

Answer (score 0):

Using WMI and the [Win32_Printer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa394363%28VS.85%29.aspx) class, I should be able to check the Availability property to see if a printer is online.

This question and answer helped:

> [how do i check if a printer is installed and ready using C#?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1622903/how-do-i-check-if-a-printer-is-installed-and-ready-using-c)

Comment: I tried that on my windows 7 box, the Availability property seems to return null. PrinterStatus worked extremely well though. It probably depends on the printer unfortunately.

Comment: The application will run exclusively on XP 64bit.

Answer (score 0):

Did you try exploring it from the PrintDialog point of view?  PrintDialog.PrinterSettings.IsDefaultPrinter...

Comment: How do you then check if it is connected using the PrinterSettings class?

Comment: The requirements are such that we won't be using PrintDialog.